# PostgreSQL: Cant match function in DLL

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I created a custom DLL containing following function:

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include <string.h>
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "utils/geo_decls.h"

PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

/* by value */

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(add_one);

Datum
add_one(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    int32 arg = PG_GETARG_INT32(0);

    PG_RETURN_INT32(arg + 1);
}
```

But when i try to create it in PgAdmin4 using next command:

```
CREATE FUNCTION add_one(INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER 
AS '$libdir/new_func', 'add_one'
LANGUAGE C STRICT ;
```

It says:

> ERROR:cannot match function "add_one" in file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/lib/new_func.dll"

> SQL-state: 42883

DLL was compiled according to [this guide](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Ejacobson/cs122b/Project/06-CFunctions.html).

Is there any way to check the list of functions in a .dll using PGAdmin? Or how can i try to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time i found out the reason why my DLL could not been read.

I used wrong compiler.

First i used compiler from [this](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/) site. Then i followed the guide in Question.

Few days ago I found another MinGW compiler. And finally everything works.

Compiler i used for the last time [here](https://www.mingw-w64.org/downloads/).

Comment: Yeah, Windows makes everything harder... There is a nice guide to compiling extension .dlls with Visual Studio here: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/